# Java awt Panel doesn't repaint from thread and only updates when I resize the window

Tags: java, awt

I'm trying to add Labels to a awt panel from a thread, and I'm calling repaint from the thread, but the panel isn't updating, and only updates when I resize the window. I tried many solutions, but none are working, so please help.

```
public class Updater extends Thread{
    private Panel p;
    public Updater(Panel p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            p.add(new Label("Text"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            p.repaint();
            System.out.println("Dodao");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Main extends Frame {    
    public Panel p;
    private void populateWindow() {      
        p = new Panel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        add(p);
    }
    public Main() {
        setSize(1000, 500);
        setResizable(true);
        setTitle("Test");   
        populateWindow();
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter () {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });     
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        Updater u = new Updater(m.p);
        u.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you using awt components?? They are ancient

Comment: I would consider moving to JavaFX or at the very least, Swing - you'll get better support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `revalidate()` instead of `repaint()`. `Revalidate()` is used for components, `repaint()` is not.

Comment: From the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()) - *"If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible."*, so, yes, it is used for AWT components.  The OP should be using both `revalidate`, which will trigger a layout pass (root cause of their problem) and `repaint` to trigger a new paint pass